# Errors while connecting MSSQL Server to android application

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2019

I am trying to connect my Android application to MSSQL server which is installed on my PC. I have previously been successful with connecting them but for some reason now I am getting a network error. I know that a direct connection shouldn't be made and a web service should be used but I am required to make a JDBC connection to the database.

The error I am getting is:

> Network error IOException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.101 (port
> 1433) from /192.168.0.100 (port 37632)

I have configured my MSSQL Server to listen on port 1433.

This is the connection class.

```
package com.example.resourceapplication.LogIn;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class ConnectionClass {
    static String ip = "192.168.0.101";
    static String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    static String db = "EKANBAN";
    static String username = "root";
    static String password = "root";

    public static Connection CONN(){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + username + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(2);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
            Log.d("Hello","It Worked");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

This class had worked for me previously but for some reason doesn't work now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you testing? Emulator (on same or different PC from MSSQL Server) or device (make/model/OS version) on same network? Have you checked from a different PC that the MSSQL Server is accessible?

Comment: Check your Windows Firewall settings to see if incoming connections are allowed to tcp/1433 from your local subnet - because the Android emulator is running on a different IP address (192.168.0.100) than your PC (169.168.0.101).

Comment: You shouldn't use JDBC drivers on Android, instead you should create REST service that mediates between your Android application and the database.